# Reading Json files with Gson -- Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I´ve been trying to read some simple `JSON` files with `Gson`. This is my `JSON`:

```
[
  {
    "OBJECTID": 14476381,
    "ROW_": null,
    "LOCATION": "1400 BLK S CAPITOL ST SE N/B",
    "ADDRESS_ID": 277954,
    "STREETSEGID": null,
    "XCOORD": 399257.7,
    "YCOORD": 133847.29,
    "TICKETTYPE": "Moving",
    "FINEAMT": 300,
    "TOTALPAID": 0,
    "PENALTY1": 300,
    "PENALTY2": null,
    "ACCIDENTINDICATOR": "No",
    "TICKETISSUEDATE": "2018-04-01T11:59:00.000Z",
    "VIOLATIONCODE": "T122",
    "VIOLATIONDESC": "SPEED 26-30 MPH OVER THE SPEED LIMIT",
    "ROW_ID": null
  },
  {
    "OBJECTID": 14476382,
    "ROW_": null,
    "LOCATION": "100 BLK MICHIGAN AVE NW E/B",
    "ADDRESS_ID": 815694,
    "STREETSEGID": 1405,
    "XCOORD": 398728.3,
    "YCOORD": 139835.9,
    "TICKETTYPE": "Moving",
    "FINEAMT": 100,
    "TOTALPAID": 0,
    "PENALTY1": 100,
    "PENALTY2": null,
    "ACCIDENTINDICATOR": "No",
    "TICKETISSUEDATE": "2018-04-01T00:35:00.000Z",
    "VIOLATIONCODE": "T119",
    "VIOLATIONDESC": "SPEED 11-15 MPH OVER THE SPEED LIMIT",
    "ROW_ID": null
  },
  ...
]
```

And this is what I have so far in my code:

```
private void readJson(String[] months) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
 for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  String month = months[i];

  try {

   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(month));
   JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(isr);

   reader.beginArray();

   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

   while (reader.hasNext()) {
    VOMovingViolations violation = gson.fromJson(reader, VOMovingViolations.class);
    data.push(violation);

   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This is my VOMovingViolation class

```
class VOMovingViolation {
 private int objectId;
 private byte row;
 private String location;
 private int addressId;
 private byte streetSegId;
 private double xCord;
 private double yCord;
 private String ticketType;
 private short fineamt;
 private short totalPaid;
 private short penalty1;
 private short penalty2;
 private String accidentIndicator;
 private String ticketIssueDate;
 private String violationCode;
 private String violationDescription;
 private byte rowId;

 public VOMovingViolations(int objectId, byte row, String location, int addressId, byte streetSegId, double xCord,
  double yCord, String ticketType, short fineamt, short totalPaid, short penalty1, short penalty2,
  String accidentIndicator, String ticketIssueDate, String violationCode, String violationDescription,
  byte rowId) {

  this.objectId = objectId;
  this.row = row;
  this.location = location;
  this.addressId = addressId;
  this.streetSegId = streetSegId;
  this.xCord = xCord;
  this.yCord = yCord;
  this.ticketType = ticketType;
  this.fineamt = fineamt;
  this.totalPaid = totalPaid;
  this.penalty1 = penalty1;
  this.penalty2 = penalty2;
  this.accidentIndicator = accidentIndicator;
  this.ticketIssueDate = ticketIssueDate;
  this.violationCode = violationCode;
  this.violationDescription = violationDescription;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(VOMovingViolations o) {
  return Integer.compare(objectId, o.objectId);
 }
}
```

I need to create an object for every `JSON object` that is read from my `JSON`, and then add it to a stack that I have created. If I implement what I have and print in console my first violation I get this

> ObjectID:0 || Adress ID:0 || Street Seg ID:0 ||  Total Paid:0 || Location:null || Ticket Issue Date:null || Accident Indicator:null || Violation Description:null

How to parse it properly?

Comment: show the `VOMovingViolations` class?

Comment: What is the size of months array?

Comment: Make sure the months length is same to number of json objects in the JSONArray

Comment: There are 6 months in my months array

Comment: But each Json is a month, what my months array contains, it is just the path where the file is saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names in `JSON` do not fit to property names in `POJO`. You need to provide extra naming convention or use `SerializedName` annotation. With naming convention it could look like below:

```
import com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public String translateName(Field f) {
                        final String name = f.getName();
                        switch (name) {
                            case "row":
                                return "ROW_";
                            case "rowId":
                                return "ROW_ID";
                            case "violationDescription":
                                return "VIOLATIONDESC";
                            default:
                                return f.getName().toUpperCase();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .create();

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<VOMovingViolations>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<VOMovingViolations> violations = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), type);
        violations.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you want to use `SerializedName` annotation you need to annotate every field in `POJO` like below:

```
@SerializedName("OBJECTID")
private int objectId;

@SerializedName("ROW_")
private byte row;

...
```

In that case you do not need to register `FieldNamingStrategy` object and your `Gson` object could look like:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

Also, do not create `Gson` in `foreach` loop. It will be enough to create it once before loop.